# SQL table referencing to an unknown table

Tags: mysql, sql, reference, key

Here are some MySQL tables :

```
CREATE TABLE inputData
(
    idInputData BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idPeriph CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    dateRecord DATETIME NOT NULL,
    dateForecast DATETIME NOT NULL,
    dataUnit VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    elevation FLOAT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idPeriph) REFERENCES peripheral(idPeriph),
    PRIMARY KEY (idInputData)
);

CREATE TABLE SRI
(
    idInputData BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    idSRI BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FOREIGN KEY (idInputData) REFERENCES inputData(idInputData),
    PRIMARY KEY (idSRI)
);

CREATE TABLE SRT
(
    idSRT BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idPeriph CHAR(8)NOT NULL,
    dateRecord DATETIME NOT NULL,
    dateForecast DATETIME NOT NULL,
    elevation FLOAT NOT NULL,
    duration TIME NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idPeriph) REFERENCES peripheral(idPeriph),
    PRIMARY KEY (idSRT)
);

CREATE TABLE coordinates
(
    latitude DECIMAL(10,6) NOT NULL,
    longitude DECIMAL(10,6) NOT NULL,
    altitude DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_idCoordinate PRIMARY KEY (latitude, longitude, altitude)
);
```

Now I wish to add a rawValue table which would contain :

- a value
- a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing to a row of `coordinate`
- a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing to a row of `inputData` *or* `SRI` *or* `SRT`

I am quite a newbie to databases.

Is my current architecture able to handle this kind of data ? If yes, how ?

Or if this is impossible, how should I build my database to be able to deal with all these data ?

Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: A foreign key to coordinates needs to reference `(latitude, longitude, altitude)`. A foreign key to `x or y or z` won't work, since there is no way for the database to dynamically know which table is referenced by a field. You'll need to have a separate FK field referencing each table.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand well it makes something like the following ?

`CREATE TABLE rawValue
(
 rawValue DOUBLE(7,3),
 
 idInputData BIGINT UNSIGNED,
 idSRI BIGINT UNSIGNED,
 idSRT BIGINT UNSIGNED,
 
 latitude DECIMAL(10,6),
 longitude DECIMAL(10,6),
 altitude DECIMAL(10,2),
 
 FOREIGN KEY (idInputData) REFERENCES inputData(idData),
 FOREIGN KEY (idSRI) REFERENCES SRI(idSRI),
 FOREIGN KEY (idSRT) REFERENCES SRT(idSRT),
 
 CONSTRAINT fk_coordinates FOREIGN KEY (latitude,longitude,altitude) REFERENCES coordinates(latitude, longitude, altitude)
);`

Comment: A bit hard to read in comment form, but it looks correct :)